# Wrong line number on stacktrace exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, stack-trace

I've got some code which errors and I'm using the stacktrace to find out what the line number is but it seems to be giving me the wrong number

Here's my code

```
Try

    Dim query As String = "Select * from table"
    Dim ds As DataSet = data.db(query)

Catch e As Exception

    Dim st As New StackTrace(True) 'This is the line number it gives me'
    Dim sf As StackFrame = st.GetFrame(0)
    Response.Write(" Method: " & sf.GetMethod().Name)
    Response.Write(" File: " & sf.GetFileName())
    Response.Write(" Line Number: " & sf.GetFileLineNumber().ToString())

End Try
```

It seems to give me the line number of where the StackTrace is starting rather than the line number of what is causing the exception

Any ideas?

Comment: Why aren't you using the stacktrace that comes with the Exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you particularly want a StackTrace object, and don't just want the string from e.StackTrace, then change your constructor call to;

```
Dim st As New StackTrace(e, True)
```

"st" will now be initialised with the source details as you're expecting.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsay49kt.aspx for details.

Answer (score 1):

The [StackTrace(true)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zh7csxz.aspx) constructor creates a new stacktrace for this point in the code.

Use the [`.Stacktrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) property of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the info from the Exception object?

```
Catch e As Exception

    Response.Write(e.StackTrace)
    Response.Write(" Method: " & e.TargetSite)
    Response.Write(" File: " & e.Source)

End Try
```

Comment: This gives me the full StackTrace but I only wanted the line number and file really

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want the StackTrace of the Exception? You are creating a new stacktrace at the line of code in the exception handler.

You want e.StackTrace instead.